# Google maps API add infowindow to array of markers on click event

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make an array of markers and have each marker open an info window with related info onclick but I either get a cannot read 'apply' property of undefined or it opens on the wrong marker; My 2 attempts were:

Cannot read apply:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.Infowindow();
for (var i=0;i<popular.length;i++){
    var mkrLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(popular[i][1], popular[i][2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: popular[i][0],
        position: mkrLatLng
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}

for (var i=0;i<markers.length;i++){
  markers[i].addListener('click', (function(){
    console.log('click');
    cont = "<div> " + markers[i].title + " </div>";
    infowindow.setContent(cont);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  })(markers));
}
```

Opens on wrong marker (Anonymous function is wrapped in another function since it got rid of the undefined error, I don't understand why):

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.Infowindow();
for (var i=0;i<popular.length;i++){
    var mkrLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(popular[i][1], popular[i][2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: popular[i][0],
        position: mkrLatLng
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function(){(function(){
        console.log('click');
        cont = "<div> " + marker.title + " </div>";
        infowindow.setContent(cont);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    })(marker)});
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure is wrong

this is example [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/45r8g9ct/)

```
//wrong
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    var count=i
    $('<p>wrong</p>').on('click',function(){
        alert(count)
    }).appendTo('body')
}
//what you want
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    createEl(i)
}
function createEl(i){
$('<p>correct</p>').on('click',function(){
        alert(i)
    }).appendTo('body')
}
```

Hope this will help you understand why you're wrong

So you need to change your code to this

```
for(){
    createMarker(parameter)
}
function createMarker(parameter){
    var marker=...,
        infowindow=....
    marker.addlistener(...)
    .......
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So just to clarify the reason it doesn't work is because not all the objects are created separately?

Answer (score 0):

Try your second code, make **var infowindow** global, maybe it'll work, I'm not sure.

Or else you can new every infowindow in forloop, and push into array, just like you handle markers.

```
var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        optimized: false,
        icon: 'red-dot.png'
    }),
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
infowindow.setContent(place.name)
infowindows.push(infowindow)
//then addlistener to marker
//markers.push(marker)
```

To open just one infowindow, use **infowindow.close()** to close all infowindows,

then call **infowindow.open(map,marker)**

Comment: This is still only opening the last infowindow in the array

Comment: put it in a function like this works for me: for(){createMarkers()}  or place.forEach(function(){createmarkers()})

Comment: Can you make a js fiddle of how you set it up? I want to make sure I didn't miss or add an extra line somewhere. I have it in for(){createMarkers()}